Energy relationship of capacitor and inductor in $RLC$ circuit
Suppose I have an $RLC$ circuit , consisting of a capacitor of capacity $C $, an inductor $L$ with non-zero internal resistance $r > 1$ ohm and a resistance $R$.
The following Claim:

When the energy stored inside the inductor is maximal, then the energy stored inside the capacitor is equal to zero.

I can understand this claim by interpretating it in terms of charges,  all the charges of the circuit have fled to the inductor thus making it's energy maximal and since there are no charges left in the capacitor the energy stored inside it is null. However looking at the differential equation of  the charge:
$$ \frac{d^2q}{dt^2} + \frac{r}{L} \frac{dq}{dt} + \frac{1}{LC}q = 0. $$
We can see that when the stored energy of the inductor is maximal, then $i$ is either minimal or maximal $ \frac{d^2q}{dt^2} = 0 $, by replacing in the differential equation we get:
$$\frac{r}{L} i + \frac{ V_c}{C} = 0 $$
so if the energy stored inside teh capacitor was null , it would mean $V_c = 0 $ and in turn $i=0$ which is clearly contradictory.
So Where's the flaw in reasoning with the differential equation?

Why do you think that the DE is wrong? Why can it not be that your intuitive assumption is wrong?

That's the problem , for some reason in every Highschool course in my country this intuitive assumption is taken to be true

Your math is entirely correct. The maximum inductive energy doesn't necessarily correspond to a minimum capacitive energy when you have a non-zero resistance in the circuit.
One way to see this is to directly solve your differential equation for the charge $q(t)$:
$$q(t) = A~e^{-rt/(2L)}\sin\left(t\sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}-\frac{r^2}{4L^2}} + \varphi\right),$$
where $A$ and $\varphi$ depend on the initial conditions. This is just a damped sinusoid as you would expect.
Now if I calculate the current $i(t) = \dot{q}(t)$:
$$i(t) = -\frac{Ar}{2L} e^{-rt/(2L)}\sin\left(t\sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}-\frac{r^2}{4L^2}} + \varphi\right) + A\sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}-\frac{r^2}{4L^2}}e^{-rt/(2L)}~\cos\left(t\sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}-\frac{r^2}{4L^2}} + \varphi\right),$$
it will not exactly be $\pi/2$ radians out of phase with respect to $q(t)$ because of the first $\sin$ term caused by $r$.
The situation is made clear if you plot $q(t)$ and $i(t)$ on top of each other for some representative values of $r,L,C$:

You can see that:

The phase difference between the current and charge deviates from $\pi/2$.
When $i(t) = 0$, $q(t)$ is either maximized or minimized, since $i(t) = \dot{q}(t)$ (as you mention in your comment).
When $q(t) = 0$, you don't necessarily have a maximum or minimum for $i(t)$.

You can also check the energies by plotting the squares of these quantities:

Clearly,

when the capacitive energy $U_C\propto q^2(t)$ is maximized, the inductive energy $U_L\propto i^2(t)$ is zero.
the reverse is however, not true. $U_L$ can be at a maximum while $U_C$ is non-zero.


May i ask for  a physical explanation as well ?  Thanks for your input .

a thing is bugging me , if the charge was maximal shouldn't i = 0  since q is maximal implies dq/dt = 0  but dq/dt is  just i .

@SahandTabatabaei Your $i$ is not quite right. You have missed the exponential decay in the cos term.

@AdamBoussif your reasoning is correct. Check my updated answer.

@Farcher Thanks for pointing that out! It's been corrected.

Thanks !  it's clearer now

No worries @AdamBoussif
